# How do I make this conditional look for empty query?

Tags: php

Edited for clarity:
Let me start by saying I'm new to this-alright?

I'm trying to send an email to a user if the $query is not NULL.  How do I do that?  I've tried a few different ways, but I'm not getting it right.  I have:

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM  events  WHERE UserID='$UserID' AND ParentEventID IS NULL";
 $result = mysql_query($query);

  if ($result != "0") {
  //Mail user if there are events:
 $to = "example@example.com";
 $subject = "New Events found!!";
 $body = "Hi!";
 if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
   echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");

  }
```

What I am trying to achieve is if the database sends back anything from `events` (IE if `ParentEventID` does indeed have items with a `NULL` value) then the email will be sent-otherwise it will not be sent.

Comment: a query can't be NULL. What you mean?

Comment: `$query` is a string... you've declared it as such just above your `if` statement. There is no way it can be `null` or empty when you've just assigned a value to it.

Comment: ... and `$query` is not an array. Thats quite confusing.

Comment: You realize that like... you're not actually making a call to the database right?

Comment: I too am confused. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @james: lol i hope that was just a pseudocode

Comment: @yes123 - I don't know what's going on in this question!

Comment: @Joel - Your edits make much more sense, but why did you have `if($query != "0")` in the first place if that's not even nearly what you intended? `$query` just contained a string, whereas `$result` actually contains the results of the query represented by the value of `$query`.

Comment: @James-what is your point?  I made a mistake, alright?

Comment: @Joel - Yes, I could guess what you were trying to achieve but I had no way of knowing whether you intended what you actually did, or what it appeared you did to me originally. The fact that your clarification edit adds a whole new variable and changes the expression in the `if` statement just made it sound (to me) that you had intentionally left out the call to `mysql_query`, when it would have been helpful to have left it in.

Comment: Yeah-I'm pretty new to this-just a hack trying to get my codez working :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$query is just a string until you do something with it, at which point it will either return a result set or FALSE.  (more or less)
http://php.net/function.mysql-query

So you would need to execute the query, and test the return value, i.e.

```
//your condition needs to be determined here, i.e. length, or something
if ($query) {
  //Mail user if there are events:
  $to = "example@example.com";
  $subject = "New Events found!!";
  $body = "Hi!";
  if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
    echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
  } else {
    echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
  }
}
```

edit: upon further inspection, if you are looking for something specific about the data returned, you need to act upon the result set and determine a condition to determine whether or not you need to send the email.

Comment: Yeah, I just need to send the email if the $result doesn't contain anything (IE if there were no results from the $query)

Comment: ok.  but you do realize you were never executing the query right?  edit:  I see you updated the code, now you just need to do something to find out the number of rows returned and base your condition that way.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Answer (score 1):

Your code will do what you want it to do.
    $query = "SELECT * FROM  events  WHERE UserID='$UserID' AND ParentEventID IS NULL"
will return a result set including the events you need to loop through.

Add a looping mechanism to go through the results and send the mail

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM  events  WHERE UserID='$UserID' AND ParentEventID IS NULL";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){


    //Mail user if there are events:
    $to = "example@example.com";//will probably be like: $row['email']
    $subject = "New Events found!!";
    $body = "Hi!";
    if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
        echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
    } else {
        echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
    }
}
```

This way you can remove the if !=0 part because if there are no results the loop will terminate itself before it has a chance to execute.

Comment: Wouldn't this send an email for every row?  I just want to send the email once if there is one or more results.

Comment: I get it now.  Change your query to read:
**$query = "SELECT * FROM  events  WHERE UserID='$UserID' AND ParentEventID IS NULL GROUP BY UserID";**
This will limit one result for each UserID.

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: How many results are you getting back from the database?  Try outputting the count.  echo count($results). Also I made a couple of edits to the code above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to check that the string is not null:

if ($query != NULL)